# Proving that a set is totally ordered but not well-ordered

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A be a non-empty arbitrary set and $L = (A , <)$ is totally ordered. Lets also define a binary relation $\leq$ in the set Seq(A) such that if $x,y \in seq(A), Dom(x) = n$ and $Dom(y) = k$ then $<x,y> \in \leq$ <=> $ (x = y) or (k < n) or \exists l(l \in n∩k$ & $x(l) < y(l)$ & ($\forall i \in l) x(i)=y(i))$. Prove that $<Seq(A), \leq>$ is totally ordered set which has a greatest element(supremum) and that $<Seq(A), \leq>$ is not well-ordered.

**Comment:**$Seq(A)$ is the set of all finite sequences in $A$. I'm again stuck with my attempts on how to prove this statement. Any help on the topic will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order $\le$ on $\operatorname{Seq}(A)$ is lexicographic order on sequences that differ in some position, but if $x\subseteq y$, then $y\le x$: a proper initial segment of a sequence $x$ is considered to be *bigger* than $x$.

HINT: For the first part, can you find an element of $\operatorname{Seq}(A)$ that is an initial segment of **every** element of $\operatorname{Seq}(A)$?

For the second, fix $a\in A$, and for each $n\in\omega$ let $x_n:n\to A$ be the constant function that sends every $k\in n$ to $a$. Consider the set $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}\subseteq\operatorname{Seq}(A)$.